# 'Error: Install jupyter notebook to the interpreter of the current project' in pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to setup Pycharm IDE in my local machine using Anaconda3 environment. When I am running a jupyter notebook with some code its showing below error in the project configuration window:

[image]

The red light Fix button even no luck.
I have checked Jupyter notbook and its already installed. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Any idea how to fix this or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Type `conda info --envs` in the console and check that the active environment is the same as the one specified in PyCharm -> Setting -> Project interpreter.

Comment: @Eskapp Yes, Same

Comment: And if you go to Settings -> Project Interpreter, can you see `jupyter_client`, `jupyter_core` and so on in the list of installed packages?

Comment: @Eskapp Installed Jupyter package and worked for me. Thanks